# Multiple importmap.json for different environments in single-spa

Tags: reactjs, micro-frontend, single-spa

In am converting the existing project into a single-spa. This application support different environments- dev,qa,prod. My requirement is to use the different import maps json based on the environment.

```
<% if (isLocal) { %>
<script type="systemjs-importmap">
{
      "imports": {
        "react": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js",
        "react-dom": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js",
        "@ppm-canvas/root-config": "//localhost:9000/ppm-canvas-root-config.js",
        "@ppm-canvas/match-upload": "//localhost:8081/ppm-canvas-match-upload.js"
      }
    }
  </script>
  <% } else { %>
    <script type="systemjs-importmap" src="https://cdn.cloudfront.net/import-map.json"></script>
  <% } %>
```

Here, I want to use something like multiple `else if` condition to be able to load different import-map.json from remote cdn.

Can someone pls help me in achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in your root-config since it is simply an [ejs template](https://ejs.co/), which is processed by Webpack. If you peek at your root-config's *webpack.config.js* you'll find `isLocal` derived there. You can add your own templateParameters there. Lastly, [import-map-deployer](https://github.com/single-spa/import-map-deployer) is a useful tool for managing multiple import maps, which can be good for multiple deployment environments.